# Create warning message inside UDF

Tags: warnings, user-defined-functions

I have a udf which I call iteratively to find the slope of a line. The goal is to only find the slope of the line near a certain point and so only a certain number of points near the line are passed into the regression. Sometimes the data is messy and the small number of points leads to an inaccurate slope, I tried to counter this by checking the R^2 value and comparing it to a desired R^2 value, and if the R^2 was not good enough, slightly increasing the number of points being used. I want to add a way to have a warning message print if the desired R^2 is not achieved even when considering all the available data.

def calc_Rp(file_name, n_points=5):
data, metadata = extract_LPR(file_name)

```
flag = 0

r2 = 0.1
r2_des = 0.999

current = data['Im'].values.reshape((-1, 1))
voltage = data['Vf'].values

n_points_max = len(voltage) / 2

while r2 < r2_des and flag == 0:

    ocp_point = np.argmin(abs(current))
    fitting_I = current[(ocp_point - n_points):(ocp_point + n_points + 1)]
    fitting_V = voltage[(ocp_point - n_points):(ocp_point + n_points + 1)]

    model = LinearRegression().fit(fitting_I, fitting_V)

    slope = model.coef_
    r2 = model.score(fitting_I, fitting_V)

    if r2 < r2_des:
        n_points += 3
        if n_points >= n_points_max:
            warnings.warn('Desired value of $R^2$ not achieved')
            flag = 1
            break
    break

return slope, metadata, r2
```